# PHP Excel Calculate Formulas

Tags: php, phpexcel

Im trying print Excel file data on a page. To do it i used PHPExcel lib, all works good, beside printing formulas, i have simple example with such formula `=SUM(C2:C5)`

I print values in a  such way:

```
 $val = $cell->getValue();
 echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
```

how can i check if $val is a formula?

`PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);` told me that it is a just another one string in my `$val`

Ofc i can calculate it in a loop, and chek if it`s a last row - insert needed info by hands, but how i can calculate it easy way?

Will be pleased to hear your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);` will always tell you string for a formula, because a formula is a string. Being a formula is related to the cell, not the data. The `getDataType()` method of the cell object will return an `'f'` for formula.

If you use `getCalculatedValue()` rather than `getValue()`, then PHPExcel will determine whether the cell contains a formula or not. If it does, then it will calculate the result and return that, otherwise it will simply return whatever would have been returned by `getValue();` The other method you might consider is `getFormattedValue()` which will return a string, formatted according to whatever rules are set for the cell. And if it was a formula cell, then it will have done the calculation as well. Particularly useful to get a date string rather than a numeric value from cells formatted as dates.

You can also avoid looping of the cells by using the `toArray()` or `rangeToArray()` methods, which will return an array of cell values, though you'd still need to loop the array. Both of these methods have arguments allowing you to set whether formulae should be calculated, and whether formatting should be applied.

Comment: Sample code for what? For testing if a cell contains a formula? Getting the calculated value for a formula cell? or using any of the toArray() type methods?

Comment: Instead of checking against `'f'` use type `PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA`. All cell types are declared in `class PHPExcel_Cell_DataType` in DataType.php

Answer (score 3):

> "how can i check if $val is a formula?"

Every formula in excel start with `=` so :

```
<?php
$String = 'SUM(B3:B8)';

# See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
# $String{} is deprecated as of PHP 6.
if($String[0] == '='){
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
function IsExcelFormula($String=null){
    if(!$String OR strlen($String) <= 0){
        return false;
    }

    $First = $String[0];

    return ($First == '=' ? true : false);
}

var_dump(IsExcelFormula('=SUM(B8:B9)')); // bool(true)
var_dump(IsExcelFormula('TOTAL(B3:B6)')); // bool(false)
?>
```

Comment: Yeap, you are right. But if my table became more wider and tomorrow i will have more then one formula, you think i should write the class with parsing all formulas? =)  I think thay already been written by developers, but i can`t find them.

Comment: Yes you may need to parse everything... But if you parse a single string (with all data from excel file) you may use regex for it.

Comment: Ok, i don`t know exactly how many records i should have. Suppose that table have 1000 records, and i need 1 loop to print table and another one loop to get sum, beside that if i need some other function like average of records or something like that, what will be happen with memmory?

Comment: Put a timer and see by yourself. It shouldn't be a problem at all. I mean, it only check if first character is equal to =. It's like having a loop and saying true or false ?

Comment: The danger is an actual string that begins with an = character... it's possible in Excel

Comment: That's true... but then need to add something that will validate the string and etc...